# Add image to different model using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use CarrierWave to upload user's pictures. my PictureUploader class have 3 version (large, small, thumb).

Now i want to add an article model then make possibility to add an image to article.

my question is :

what is the best way : create a new uploader for articles ? or just use the existing picture uploader ? if so how to add conditions to say for example : large, small and thumb are just for user model, and "other_version" is for article model

Answer (score 1):

I would make a different uploader in case your article pictures differ from your user pictures in some way. Even if they don't now, keeping them separated will give you more flexibility later.

Remember the uploaders are just Ruby classes, so if they do share some functionality you can use inheritance/mix-ins so you're not copying code.

Comment: thank you @loganSerman for the quick answer, i think that the idea of using inheritance is not the best because the uploader class will inherit also versions ... you can't say: inherit for me just something and ignore some others.the idea of ​​separation seems to me logically good :)